# Enable Assertions in Ant JUnit 5 Launcher

Tags: ant, junit5

I'm migrating my company from JUnit 4 to 5.  I'd love to also be migrating us from Ant to Gradle, but one step at a time.  We previously used the `<assertions>` tag to enable assertions in our JUnit task.

The new ant-junitlauncher doesn't seem to support this option.  I also tried passing it a `<jvmarg value="-ea" />` and setting up a properties file with assertions enabled.  None of those passed my first check to make sure assertions are enabled during tests.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Since the `junitlauncher` for Ant is relatively new, it could be that it's simply not supported yet. Have you considered asking the Ant team directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the following environment variable to get my Java options set: `export ANT_OPTS="-ea -Xmx512m"`.  Not ideal for anyone running multiple projects, and it seems like a -D command line should take care of it similarly, but I was not able to make that work and moved on as is.